# how to match an url with django urlconf?

Tags: python, django, url, urlconf

Im implementing a payment module called mercadopago (like paypal) and I need to handle a http request that is send to my site when someone make a payment(IPN) with information in in an url of this type:

> POST /notifications?topic=payment&id=identificador-de-notificacion-de-pago

(mercadopago send a POST request  to my site every time a payment impact)

but i cant make it match with the django url system. i tried the following url:

```
    url(r'^notifications$', 'views.notifications', name='notifications'),
```

I tried with diferent combination and consulted the apache log file and threw me error 500

The view that handdle the url is the following:

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def IpnProxy(request, **kwargs):
        mp = mercadopago.MP("*********", "*********") 
        paymentInfo = mp.get_payment_info(kwargs["id"])
        if paymentInfo["status"] == 200:
            return paymentInfo["response"]
        else:
            return None
```

I dont know if have to configure singals or something else.

Maybe im getting it wrong but mercadopago make the post request to my server, I cant change that. Here is their documentation 
http://developers.mercadopago.com/documentation/instant-payment-notifications?lang=en_US
And here is their example project in python:
https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-python/blob/master/examples/instant-payment-notifications/receive-ipn.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encoding the parameters incorrectly for a POST in Django. POST requests get their parameters encoded in the request body.  Please take a look at the [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/) documentation for Django. If you really want to use the URL you provided you will need to use a GET instead of a POST.

--- EDIT ---

Give the following a try:
In your urls.py file after you've imported notification.

```
url(r'^notification$', notification, name='notification')
```

In your settings.py:

```
APPEND_SLASH=False
```

You will almost certainly need to also turn of CSRF protection since you won't have a CSRF cookie.

You will be able to retrieve the parameters as follows:

```
def notification(request, **kwargs):
    body = "topic = '{0}'\nid = '{1}'\n".format(request.GET.get('topic'), request.GET.get('id'))
    response = HttpResponse(body, content_type="text/plain")
    return response
```

Testing then gives us:

```
hackworth:~$ curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/notification?topic=payment&id=identificador-de-notificacion-de-pago"
topic = 'payment'
id = 'identificador-de-notificacion-de-pago'
```

**All of the above is a bad idea since POST requests generally have a body, and Django really does not expect query parameters on a POST url. Also, there is now a security vulnerability since CSRF protection had to be turned off to make this work.**

The way the documentation reads, you will receive a URL from mercadopago that you retrive with a get request. It is not clear that that they will send you a POST request with query parameters.

Comment: Maybe im getting it wrong but mercadopago make the post request to my server, I cant change that. Here is their documentation 
http://developers.mercadopago.com/documentation/instant-payment-notifications?lang=en_US
And here is their example project in python:
https://github.com/mercadopago/sdk-python/blob/master/examples/instant-payment-notifications/receive-ipn.py

Answer (score 2):

Everything after the `?` mark is a [Query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) with request GET parameters. They are not included into the url patterns in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^notifications/$', view_notifications)
```

Get of the `GET` parameters from [`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) `QueryDict` in the view:

```
def view_notifications(request):
    topic = request.GET.get('topic')
    print topic
```

See also:

- [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response)
- [Capturing url parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)
- [Django and query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711349/django-and-query-string-parameters)

Comment: Thx but the request is a POST, i've just edited my question, i hope u can help me.