# how to make a url pattern for a query string django

Tags: django

After the form is submitted a get request with parameters will be created, I was struggling with the regex in the urls.py I want to know the pattern for this Get request

```
/create-usecase/?usecase_name=test&category=1&sub_category=msameh&csrfmiddlewaretoken=m4UIwr0qsWuAwVJq7OCLt6KY8EnFrlFDNGJcTUicY2rUylMgFMzILElZaPDbNLtr
```

and how to get these values in the view function

Comment: Note that you don't need `{% csrf_token %}` in your form if you are making GET requests.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711349/django-and-query-string-parameters

Comment: Once you implemented the view which takes parameters from the GET, you can *add* a view with parameters in the URL that redirects to the query view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query string is never part of the routing. The view at `/create-usecase/` will need to inspect `request.GET` directly or otherwise and operate based on that.

Comment: so how to send the values of usecase_name, category and sub_category to another view function

Comment: Get them from `request.GET`.

Comment: I am not sure how its going to work because in the urls.py I have a path of pattern 'create-usecase/' which fire up the function called create_usecase I want to take the values from the form in the create-user template and transfer it to another function which is questions but to do that i must use another url pattern which i don't know how to use request.get