# How to recognize urls with get parameters un django?

Tags: django, regex, get, django-urls

I am learning Django, usually I use urls like [www.mysite.com/post/1](http://www.mysite.com/post/1), and I have understood them because they are well described in the documentation.
Now I need to create a url like: [www.mysite.com/calendar/?day=21&?month=12&year=2020](http://www.mysite.com/calendar/?day=21&?month=12&year=2020), I don't understand what should I write in my ulrpatterns list.
I have tried something like this:

```
url(r'^search/(?P<parameter>\w+)', views.calendar, name='calendar')
```

but it doesn't work.
What should I write as regex expression?

Thanks

Comment: I think this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711911/683329 should work?
Short version: The part from '?' onwards is not part of the URL path, it's treated separately.

Answer (score 2):

These parameters are not part of the path, you can't capture them using the url patterns.

You can access them directly inside your view by using `request.GET`, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET).

A common pattern is the following:

```py
def calendar(request):
    day = request.GET.get("day")  # Will be None if "day" isn't in the query
    month = request.GET.get("month")
    year = request.GET.get("year")
    [...]
```