# Django receiving POST URL

Tags: django, post, jira, webhooks, django-urls

I'm using Jira webhooks to communicate with my Django app. In Jira, I set POST URL to:

```
/api/webhooks/jira?issue_id=EXAMPLE_ISSUE_ID&secret=EXAMPLE_SECRET&user_id=EXAMPLE_USER_ID&user_key=EXAMPLE_KEY
```

My app `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/webhooks/jira", views.webhook, name='webhook')
]
```

How can I get information about  `issue_id`, `secret`, `user_id`, and `user_key` (Those values aren't included in json that I recveive via post) and what is the proper way to set `path` in my `urls.py`?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711349/django-and-query-string-parameters/3711911