# Using query strings in django GET

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've a GET request in django rest framework that fetches data using kwargs.

```
class FetchUser(APIView):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            email = kwargs.get('email')
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            return Response(UserSerializer(user).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except(KeyError, User.DoesNotExist) as e:
            return Response(str(e), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Here's my url

```
path(r'fetch/<str:email>', FetchUser.as_view(), name='fetch_user'),
```

However I want to fetch the data using a query string,

Something like `http://base/fetch?email=something`

How do I modify my urls and views to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711349/django-and-query-string-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like -

```
def get_queryset(self):
    cityId = self.request.GET.get('city')
    # this reads query param
    if cityId is None:
        queryset = branch.objects.all()
        # queryset = branch.objects.none()
    else:
        queryset = branch.objects.filter(city=cityId)
    return queryset
```

and your query can be

```
http://base/?city=something
```

Comment: what would the url look like?

Comment: http://base/?city=something

Comment: I meant my urls.py. I tried this `path(r'^fetch/$', FetchUser.as_view(), name='fetch_user'),` and it doesn't work.

Comment: path('city/', cityView.as_view(), name='city name'),  show your urls file, have you used defaultrouters ?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to configure urls.py like this:

```
path('base/fetch/', FetchUser.as_view()),
```

Then, you will pass the parameters as query string on the URL, using ? and &:

```
http://base/fetch?param1=something&param2=something_else
```

On your views.py, the query string parameters will be available in request.GET, and you can get them like this:

```
class FetchUser(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    try:
        param1 = request.GET.get('param1')
        param2 = request.GET.get('param2')
        ...
```