# Want to add '?id= ' in urls.py

Tags: python, django, url

I have urls.py in my project.
I want to create URL like `localhost:8000/v1/user?id=1`
Can anyone help me how I can create the above URL.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add specifically `id=1`, or can id be any number?

Comment: Can be any integer number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711349/django-and-query-string-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part right from the question mark (`?`) is the [*query string* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). The `urls.py` do *not* inspect the querystring, they only care about the *path* (the part *left* from the question mark).

The `urls.py` thus uses:

```
urlpatterns = [path('/v1/user', some_view)]
```

in the view you then can access the last value that associates with the `id` key with `request.GET['id']`. Here `request.GET` is a [**`QueryDict`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict): it is a dictionary-like object but a key can be associated with *multiple* values. You thus will need to check if the `id` appears in the `QueryDict`, perhaps validate that it occurs only once, and check if it is numerical (or some other format).

While it is possible to work with a query string. Usually the idea is in Django that if a parameter is required, you somehow encode it in the path, not in the query string. The query string is normally used for *optional* data, for example to filter a list.